# I have txt file that stored in my DB and I want to display it in table format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can reach the [Header] via SUBSTRING(), but I can't understand how to loop all the rows and present the needed information in Temp table. See the file template below:

```
    4a65d4fg65sa4g <br>
    26801 <br>
    1524125 <br>
    afajkj;41931vb <br>

    ga-q981=94=619jg;lk <br>
    [Header]:Entry  Time <br>
    [Row]:    0  3:48:44  <br>
    [Row]:    1  3:49:02  <br>
    [Row]:    2  3:49:04  <br>
    [Row]:    3  3:54:30  <br>
    [Row]:    4  3:54:55  <br>
    [Row]:    5  3:55:01  <br>
    [Row]:    6  3:55:23  <br>
    [Row]:    7  3:55:28  <br>
    [Row]:    8  3:55:56  <br>
    [Row]:    9  3:56:10  <br>
    [Row]:   10  3:56:16  <br>
    [Row]:   11  4:00:00  <br>
    [Row]:   12  4:07:34  <br>
    [Row]:   13  4:28:35  <br>
    [Row]:   14  4:33:00  <br>

--------------------------------------------- <br>
[Row]:   15  0:00:00 <br>
[Row]:   16  0:00:00 <br>
. <br>
. <br>
. <br>
. <br>
```

Comment: The usual approach is to parse the file into something SQL Server can handle *before* you process it with SQL. T-SQL is a bad language to have to do string processing in. If you have SQL Server 2016+, `STRING_SPLIT` is available. On earlier versions, there are workarounds, but you really shouldn't bother and focus on getting an external import process to do its job instead. This can be as simple as preprocessing the file with a text editor with reasonably powerful replacement functions.

Comment: If those lines really do contain markup like `<br>` (note that you really should be using self closing markup now too! (`<br />`)) then, like @JeroenMostert said, SQL Server really isn't the right tool for this. There are plenty of tools out there for processing text, use that to "normalise" your data more, and then import that into SQL Server.

Comment: I think you should use excel for different columns and import that excel from SQL server directly. In excel you can use "Text to columns" so that data can be split into different columns and after that can be imported to SQL as a table.

Comment: Is that data in multiple rows or in one row? If one row, are there carriage returns between the lines? Please indicate which rows you want to pull out in your example.

Comment: I must perform this conversion in SQL Server, but I do have SQL Server 2016.
Let me look into STRING_SPLIT